# How to make selected item clickable in bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I have a bottom navigation, I check the selected item on its selection, and this prevent it from re selecting the same item again.

So if I am on the home screen and I click home screen navigation item again, it does not do anything.

I have a case where I need to make home navigation item selectable even if its already selected.

This is my code that I run in onCreate method.

```
public void updateNavigationBarState() {
    int actionId = getNavigationMenuItemId();
    selectBottomNavigationBarItem(actionId);
}


void selectBottomNavigationBarItem(int itemId) {
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0, size = menu.size(); i < size; i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        boolean shouldBeChecked = item.getItemId() == itemId;
        if (shouldBeChecked) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            item.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make item clickable even if its selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use **setNavigationItemSelectedListener**. 
Like below

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menuItemId:
                        // do your stuff here
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            });
```